# Laravel 5.3 Scout Search

Tags: laravel

Произвожу поиск как указано в документации:

```
$pages = Page::search('Test')->get();
```

Выдает:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::search()

Как решить проблему?

Comment: А `Page` — это у вас точно модель? Как объявляете?

Comment: use App\Models\Page;

Comment: Нет, я про саму модель, вроде `class Page extends Eloquent`.

Comment: А сам scout установлен?

Comment: Плюсанул, команда `php artisan scout:import App\\Models\\Page` должна быть выполнена

Answer (score 2):

Убедитесь, что вы не забыли подключить trait **Laravel\Scout\Searchable** в вашу модель.